# Minted breaks the bibliography formatting

Tags: bibliographies, minted

Does anybody know if {minted} in latex has any conflict with other referencing packages? Why does it have this weird impact on the formatting of the reference? The references continue growing in one column, in a two-column format, leaving the column on the right entirely empty. But references are cited properly, it's only that they don't appear in the document. Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\newtheorem{Define}{Definition}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % For sout
\usepackage{varwidth} %for line breaks in algorithm
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
% \usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}   
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}
%\setminted{fontsize=\small,baselinestretch=1}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[binary-units=true]{siunitx} %For SI units
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{breqn}
%% More for Algorithm
\usepackage[ruled,norelsize,linesnumbered, noend]{algorithm2e}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother
\usepackage{balance}
\begin{document}

\title{Ttile..}

\maketitle

% As a general rule, do not put math, special symbols or citations
% in the abstract or keywords.
\begin{abstract}
Abstract ..
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle
Apples are good for health \cite{ref1, ref2,ref3,ref4,ref5,ref6,ref7}.

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\balance
\bibliography{test}
```

and in the bib-file I have only one, very-long reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) reproducing the problem? It is hard to say anything helpful without any code.

Comment: Thank you for the quick comment. Sure, here is a dummy example.

Comment: So, all 7 references are cited. but only 5 appears in the document, even the 5th one is half, it looks like all of them are present but they just don't show there.

Comment: and in case the refernces are more, all references that could come in the right column, they will not show, and then rest continues in the left column on the next page. Sorry for a lot of text. and I included all the packages that I use.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you sure `minted` causes this (i.e., if you remove `\usepackage{minted}`, does the problem go away)? Maybe `\usepackage{balance}` is a problem, I would not be surprised (but I didn't test it) if this package does not work well together with the IEEE class.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, if I remove \usepackage{minted, then it works fine. Oh wait, the problem goes away if I remove \usepackage{balance} as well. Interesting. Thumbs up :)

Comment: Not sure how can I mark this as answer.